# Steam Link not sending sound to TV

Tags: steam, technical-issues, pc, windows-7, steam-link

When I start Steam Link I don't receive any sound from the TV. 
I checked sound settings and they were enabled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried a different HDMI cable?

Comment: I used hdmi cable wich comes with steam link

Comment: I had some trouble with this the first time I set mine up.  Are you using a Desktop PC as the source?  I didn't realize I had the desktop on mute and as a result I couldn't get anything on the Steam Link.

Comment: Yes, Im using a desktop pc, and the sound is not muted.

Comment: Okay, so have you tried a different HDMI cable?

Comment: Solved, it was the hdmi input of TV, it is wrong and I changed to other hdmi input, thanks.

Comment: @SilverSurfer While the answer to this question is essentially user error - check the input, can you please post your answer to your own question and accept it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, it was the HDMI input of TV, it is wrong, I changed to other HDMI input and now it works fine.